# jQuery getting input:nth-child(n) value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

What I'm trying to is when the model number changes, the value of price will change. And for me to get the price I would be needing the id number and the quantity.

So I got this HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 topnav">
    <span>                                                              
        <input name="prodid[]" type="text" id="form-field-icon-1" class="input-small" placeholder="Product ID" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <input name="model[]" type="text" id="form-field-icon-2" class="input-small" onchange="getprice($(this));"placeholder="Model" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <input name="qty[]" type="text" id="form-field-icon-3" class="input-small" placeholder="Quantity" />
    </span>
        <input name="price[]" type="text" id="form-field-icon-2" class="input-small" placeholder="Price" readonly="readonly" />                                                             
    <span>
        <button class="btn btn-minier btn-yellow">Add</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
function getprice(thisObj) {
    var prodid = thisObj.closest('div').children().children("input:first").val();
    var modelid = thisObj.val();
    var qty = thisObj.closest('div').children().children("input:nth-child(2)").val();
}
```

The value of qty that I get is undefined but when I change the nth-child to 1, I get the value of what I input. In my console.log, there is a value.
     context: input#form-field-icon-2.input-small

thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Because the `input` is the first child of its parent `span`.

You need

```
var qty = thisObj.closest('div').children(':nth-child(3)').children("input").val();
```

or the easiest way is to find the input by its name

```
var qty = thisObj.closest('div').find('input[name="qty[]"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

```
var test = thisObj.closest('div').children().children("input:nth-child(1)");
var model = $(test[1]).val();
```

I was able to get what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<input>` with index 2 in markup you've provided.

If you want to get second  inside div class="col-sm-9 topnav" then simply do this:

```
var second = $("div.topnav input")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getprice(thisObj) {
    var prodid = thisObj.closest('div').children().children("input:first").val();
    var modelid = thisObj.val();
    var qty = thisObj.closest('div').children().children("input:eq(1)").val();
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You should change your javascript code like this

```
function getprice(thisObj) {
    var prodid = thisObj.closest('div').children().children("input:eq(0)").val();
    var modelid = thisObj.val();
    var qty = thisObj.closest('div').children().children("input:eq(1)").val();
}
```

*:nth-child(3) in not working properly for input fields. Remember one thing :eq array is start from 0 index.*